# In C#, is there a difference between setting properties using a class constructor and setting the property members directly?

Tags: c#, class, oop, properties, member

In C#, is there a benefit or different result yielded when you set properties of a object using the class constructor vs creating an object and setting the values of the properties directly? I am new to C# so correct me if I am using terminology incorrectly.

This is the class:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int Age;
        public string FirstName;
        public string LastName;
        
        public Employee(string firstName, string lastName, int age)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
            Age = age;
        }
    }
```

When instantiating the object I know I can pass arguments to the constructor. Using:

```
Employee myEmployee = new Employee("MyName", "MySurname", 30);
```

If I comment out the class constructor I can still set the properties. Is there a difference doing it this way over the other?

```
Employee myEmployee = new Employee(){
                FirstName = "MyName",
                LastName = "Surname",
                Age = 32 
            };
```

All trainings I have taken only shows using the constructor. I am not sure if certain situations would call for using one method over the other or if one actually performs differently.

Comment: None of `Age`, `FirstName`, `LastName` are properties...

Comment: There is one difference: When you don't have a public setter the constructor will work but the properties initialization won't. To resolve it, use the ```init``` access modifier. And @Sweeper is right... those are fields, not properties.

Comment: There answer is no, maybe, sometimes. Depends if someone has coded the constructor or setters to have side effects. Sometimes properties are read only, sometimes properties are the only way to set the state. Sometimes the author wants you to use the constructor as they are in charge of constructing and may need to set specific state. When the class is simple, and there are no setters or construction side effects, there is no major difference

Comment: `In C#, is there a benefit or different result yielded when you set properties of a object using the class constructor vs creating an object and setting the values of the properties directly?` The benefit of the constructor is you can be confident _all_ of the values were provided. The advantage of the other syntax is you can support a subset of the properties / fields being set.

Comment: One fundamental difference between the two is if you have a constructor that takes parameters, the parameters are evaluated _before_ the constructor is called. If you use the other syntax, the parameters are evaluated _after_ the constructor is called. https://dotnetfiddle.net/3neBIg

Comment: Its kind of like asking, is there any difference between using a front door or the back door, well it depends if there is bear trap on the back door. Look ideally, constructors are for constructing, there are even special init properties that make it even more useful to construct using constructors, additionally its a very common school of thought these days that objects should try to limit dirty little fingers from changing state via properties. Ergo, if you need to constructor something, make the state be known at construction by using the constructor, that's what it is there for

Comment: The properties are only assigned after the constructor is executed, but before the variable is assigned. Which means the values are not visible in the constructor, or any base type.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no difference programmatically, but there are semantic differences.

The benefit of using the field initialization is that you can pick and choose what fields to set and leave others null. For example:

```
var employee = new Employee 
{
   FirstName = "Bob"
};
```

`LastName` is now `null` and `Age` is now `0`. Leaving fields uninitialized like this may cause issues when it's time to use the employee object.

In this situation, it's best to mark all of the fields as Nullable properties by placing a question mark at the end of the type. For example:

`public int? Age { get; set; }`

This will tell the compiler that these fields could be null since you may have not initialized them. You will get warnings if you try to directly dereference them without checking if they are null first.

But if you want to ensure that every `Employee` has a `FirstName`, `LastName`, and `Age`, you should use a constructor the requires those fields.